# How to set hourly limit to my api from an IP in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, api, cpanel

I am developing a free API to get `JSON` response. Is it possible to limit users accessing my API morethan 10 times in an hour? How can I do that in `apache` using `.htaccess` or something through cpanel.

Comment: Since there is no persistent storage on the http server level I'd say you have to do this in your application logic.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for the comment. Actually I wanted to block the request before executing any code. So it is not possible right?